# Directed graph: checking for cycle in adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph

There is an alternative method respect to the DFS algorithm to check if there are cycles in a directed graph represented with an adjacency matrix?

I found piecemeal information on the properties of matrices.
Maybe I can multiply matrix A by itself n times, and check if there is non-zero diagonal in each resulting matrix.

While this approach may be right, how can I extract explicitly the list of vertices representing a cycle?
And what about the complexity of this hypothetical algorithm?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your method is right, but it seems hard to find exactly vertices

Answer (score 2):

Let's say after `n` iterations, you have a matrix where the cell at row `i` and column `j` is `M[n][i][j]`

By definition `M[n][i][j] = sum over k (M[n - 1][i][k] * A[k][j])`. Let's say `M[13][5][5] > 0`, meaning it has a cycle of length 13 starting at 5 and ending at 5. To have `M[13][5][5] > 0`, there must be some `k` such that `M[12][5][k] * A[k][5] > 0`. Let's say `k = 6`, now you know one more node in the cycle (6). It also follows that `M[12][5][6] > 0` and `A[6][5] > 0`

To have `M[12][5][6] > 0`, there must be some `k` such that `M[11][5][k] * A[k][6] > 0`. Let's say `k = 9`, now, you know one more node in the cycle (9). It also follows that `M[11][5][9] > 0` and `A[9][6] > 0`

Then, you can do the same repetitively to find other nodes in the cycle.

Comment: Your method seems really interesting, thanks! What about the complexity of this algorithm compared to BFS? You think it might be more efficient in terms of computational cost?

Comment: I find this answer very insightful; however the approach is actually the [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm for shortest paths. Its runtime is worse than DFS, however it can potentially discover all nodes which lie on cycles in a single pass. Choice of the algorithm depends on the goal; is the goal to find all nodes which lie on cycles or to find an arbitrary cycle if it exists?

Comment: @Codor The goal is to list all cycles and, for each cycle, list all nodes that lie on the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Depth-first search can be modified to decide the existence of a cycle. The first time that the algorithm discovers a node which has previously been visited, the cycle can be extracted from the stack, as the previously found node must still be on the stack; it would make sense to use a user-defined stack instead of the call stack. The complexity would be `O(|V|+|E|)`, as for unmodified depth-first search itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Probably implement DFS is easier, considering the wide availability of literature about the algorithm.